# DigitalMicrograph TEM control "beam blank"

Tags: hardware, dm-script

I've been trying to automate the process for acquiring a series of images using DM script. And in between acquisitions there's the processing time, which the electron beam is still illuminating the specimen. Is there any DM script function for controlling the beam blank (so that it also applies to beam-sensitive materials)? I'd appreciate any feedback/response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**GMS 3.2** has such a command - but not all systems support it. You can use `EMHasBeamBlanker()` to check this and then use `EMSetBeamBlanked( bool )` and `bool EMGetBeamBlanked()`

Comment: Thank you @BmyGuest !!! Unfortunately our microscope is on GMS 1.8...I'll just have to find other ways instead.